# Guest Ubuntu VM speed up clock

Tags: virtualbox, time

I have an Ubuntu host machine with virtual box installed. For software testing purposes I have a virtual machine with Ubuntu Server 14.04 and official Virtual Box guest additions installed. And I need to speed up virtual machine clock say 4x times. I have found this article.

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#warpguest

But time still goes with same speed (`date` utility). What could be the problem? Does anyone have any other solutions to speed up clock in ubuntu virtual machine?

Comment: Did you also disable TimeSync of the guest to host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works!

I have disabled time sync with following commands:

```
VBoxManage setextradata "VM Name" VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled 1
VBoxManage setextradata "VM Name" VBoxInternal/TM/TSCTiedToExecution 1
VBoxManage setextradata "VM Name" VBoxInternal/TM/WarpDrivePercentage 400 # means 4x times faster
```

Note, in Virtual Box 4.3.x you need to enter parameters without quotes [(see comments here)](http://stevenormrod.com/2012/10/disabling-time-sync-in-virtualbox/).

Also you need totally power off and start the virtual machine… Simple reboot for some reason didn't work.